# How to change the code in Lucene 4.0

Tags: java, lucene

Here is the code:

```
protected Document getDocument(File f) throws Exception {
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new Field("contents", new FileReader(f),Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS));
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
    doc.add(new Field("filename",  f.getName(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
    doc.add(new Field("fullpath", f.getCanonicalPath(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
    return doc;
}
```

I change the version from 3.6 to 4.0. So there are some method are deprecated.
FOr example:
doc.add(new Field) the Field is deprecated. Field.TermVector the TremVector is deprecated.And the Field.Index the Index is also deprecated.

Comment: There are release notes that document what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

In the [`Field` documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html), they list a set of Field subclasses that it pays to get to know:

> Most users should use one of the sugar subclasses: IntField, LongField, FloatField, DoubleField, ByteDocValuesField, ShortDocValuesField, IntDocValuesField, LongDocValuesField, PackedLongDocValuesField, FloatDocValuesField, DoubleDocValuesField, SortedBytesDocValuesField, DerefBytesDocValuesField, StraightBytesDocValuesField, StringField, TextField, StoredField.

In particular, you'll find [`TextField`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/TextField.html) and [`StringField`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/StringField.html) useful, for the fields you have listed.

[The Migration Guide](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/MIGRATE.html) has more information on changes in 4.0.